# Should I create a class or add a property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture

I am currently designing a software to track and manage an individual's finance using C#/WPF and the MVVM pattern. This is a personal project I am doing on my own, that I have started out of interest in gaining more knowledge with these technologies and to put in my portfolio, so having no time/money/etc constraints, I am trying to take the best decisions design-wise.

In the model part of my software, I currently have classes like `Expense` and `Income` that inherit a public interface `ITransaction`. I also have classes like `BankAccount`, `CreditCard` and `Loan` that inherit a public interface `IAccount`. Expense and Income don't have any difference between them, they have the same properties like `Name`, `Description`, etc. Same goes for `BankAccount`, `CreditCard` and `Loan`: they all have the same properties. Since these are in the model part of MVVM, to my knowledge, they shouldn't have methods since they shouldn't have any logic implemented directly in them (other than properties validation that can be done in the properties themselves).

A question I am having early on (I actually am just starting this project), is whether I should change that design since, while they model something concrete of the real life, they have no difference at all between them (`Expense` is just a copy paste of `Income`, etc). Should I be changing my design to have, for example, a `TransactionType` property in a `Transaction` class in order to distinguish between an income and an expense instead of having the class type do that difference?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method in the long run?

Comment: Yeah, i agree with @GrantWinney, keep your code clean so if you will need to change it later you just copy paste it and you are done.

Comment: @GrantWinney Let's say that I keep things the way they are and the Expense and Income class never change (so they basically stay a copy paste of each other, but only differing in the treatment I do with them in the ViewModel). Wouldn't that be considered a bad design later on in the project?

Comment: @Choub890 can i give a piece of advice: develop for what you need now, do it in a way so you can extend it later if you need it and you should be fine

Comment: I agree with @GrantWinney also.  I don't think you can go too far wrong either way, but using separate classes is safer, gives you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I will keep my design the way it is there, which is with and `Expense` and `Income` class inheriting the `ITransaction` interface (same goes for `BankAccount`, `Loan` and `CreditCard` with the `IAccount` interface) because, as pointed out by comments, it would be the easiest to refactor if even comes a day where I need different behaviors from those classes. This could be as simple as different property validation logic (which could be the case even though they `Expense` and `Income` just have properties and no methods).

Also, a class is something that should be modeled from an object or a concept of real life that your software uses. I think, for that reason, that `Expense`, `Income` and `BankAccount`, `Loan` and `CreditCard` should be classes even if for the moment there is no difference in logic between them, because those are concepts or "objects" that my software has to model.

Answer (score 1):

If you're torn between the two, you could start off with the simpler option - a single class with a property indicating the transaction type.

```
public class Transaction
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public TransactionType TransType { get; set; }
}

public enum TransactionType
{
    Income,
    Expense
}
```

If you decide later that the two concepts are diverging, and you need separate functionality for one or the other, you could always create separate classes that extend `Transaction`, which should hopefully prevent some refactoring headaches:

```
public class Credit : Transaction
{
    public Credit()
    {
        TransType = TransactionType.Income;
    }

    public void SomeOtherMethodYouRealizedYouNeed()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Expense : Transaction
{
    public Expense()
    {
        TransType = TransactionType.Expense;
    }

    public int SomeNewProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Just my two cents...

Comment: I prefer the inheritance model from the beginning. It almost always has to be refactored to this later. I wouldn't even consider to have the `SomeType` property anymore now. Having both the inheritance and the `Type` property at the same time is redundant anyway so why bother at all? It only makes things more complicated.